# How to correctly use KeyboardEvent on Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I have a problem making a KeyboardEvent work in the game I'm starting. I have three classes, one for handling the levels, one that is the actual level and one to represent the avatar:

**Level**

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Fase extends Cena
{
    var avatar:Avatar;

    public function Fase()
    {
        // constructor code
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
    }

    public function onAdded(e:Event)
    {
        avatar = new Avatar();
        this.addChild(avatar);
        avatar.x = stage.width/2;
        avatar.y = 30;

    }

    public function die()
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
        (this.parent as ScreenHandler).removeChild(this);
    }

}
```

**Avatar**

```
public class Avatar extends MovieClip
{

    public function Avatar()
    {
        // constructor code
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
    }

    public function onAdded(e:Event)
    {
        //stage.focus=this;
        this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, apertou);
    }

    public function apertou(event:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        trace("o");
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
        {
            this.x++;
        }
    }

}
```

I have all the packages on both classes an all works if I use the stage.focus=this on the Avatar, but if I click somewhere else during game excecution the focus is lost and it doesn't work anymore. Please can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard events only trigger when the object they're assigned to are the current focus.

Fortunately, the `stage` always has focus by default. This means you can add your event listeners to the stage to always have the keyboard events trigger as expected:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, apertou);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the key handler from the avatar to the level or stage and then move your avatar in there.

```
public class Fase extends Cena
{
    var avatar:Avatar;

    public function Fase()
    {
        // constructor code
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
    }

    public function onAdded(e:Event)
    {
        avatar = new Avatar();
        this.addChild(avatar);
        avatar.x = stage.width/2;
        avatar.y = 30;
        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, apertou);

    }

    public function die()
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
        (this.parent as ScreenHandler).removeChild(this);
    }

    public function apertou(event:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
        {
            avatar.x++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still it only works with the stage.focus on the class that has the keyboard code.